# Show all rows in datatables, after it has initialised

Tags: jquery, datatable

How do you show all rows on datatables from a click of a button, AFTER the datatables has already initialised?

When I try this:

```
$('#showAll').click(function() {
    var oSettings = product_list.fnSettings();
    oSettings._iDisplayLength = 50;
    product_list.fnDraw();
});
```

I get this error:

[image]

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

---

tried to use the new method, and nothing happens:

```
var oSettings = product_list.settings();
oSettings._iDisplayLength = 50;
product_list.draw();
```

I am using datatables `v1.10.x`

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it: https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len()

```
product_list.page.len(-1).draw();
```